# URLs in CiviMail give a 404 not found error

Tags: civimail

CiviCRM 5.14.0.

This is a new installation with WordPress. I sent a test mail. I checked out the unsubscribe link, which resolves to [this](http://test.vietfeir.com/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fmailing%2Foptout&reset=1&jid=19&qid=23&h=352376ef3e159129)

That turns out to not be a valid link. I have a feeling there must be a setting somewhere for that.

Comment: I checked the CMS database integration in system settings and this should be the valid link. Is there another place I need to set this?

Answer (score 2):

I added Options -Indexes to the Apache configuration file which changed the behavior of the link. The URL is controlled by a page in WordPress, which is creates a permalink.